# Header of the table must be centered, all other rows aligned to left

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[here]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|}
            \hline 
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{SED}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\% compressione}} \\
            \cline{1-2}
            \textbf{MC} & \textbf{DP} & \\ 
            \hline 
            \hline
            0.00016032 & 0.0001750267 & 10\%\\
            \hline
            \end{tabular} 
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

It realizes this image:
[image]

The first two columns are correctly formatted to the left, but I want it so that just MC and DP will be centered, how can I do that?

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation of the package `booktabs`, see CTAN: http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs

Answer (score 11):

Like you did it with the "SED": with `\multicolumn`:

```
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{MC}}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `makecell` package can be handy here, as it allows to have a common formatting for all column headers declared in preamble.: the contents of a `\makecell`  or `\thead` command is  by default  both vertically aand horizontally centred. It also defines a command for hlines of varying thickness. Consider also using the `booktabs`  package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor} 

\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\color{Tomato3}\bfseries}
\setcellgapes{3pt}


\begin{document}

{\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width1pt}p{.5in}|p{1in}|p{1in}|p{1in}!{\vrule width1pt}}
\Xhline{1pt}
\thead{S. No.} & \thead{Book Name} & \thead{Author} &
  \thead{Publisher}\\
\hline
a & b & c & d\\
\Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabular}}
 \vskip 1cm
\begin{tabular}{p{.5in}*{3}{p{1in}}}
\toprule
\thead{S. No.} & \thead{Book Name} & \thead{Author} &
  \thead{Publisher}\\
\cmidrule(l{5pt}r{5pt}){1-4}
a & b & c & d\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]